# Unable to search objects in s3 using metadata efficiently

Tags: aws-s3-client

I am looking for aws s3 service which can search all the objects and return those objects whose metadata matches with the input metadata...

I read couple of stackoverflow threads...people say that there is no s3 service for it, rather I should loop through every object and find it...is there any alternative??